Where does the "cdrom" kickstart option search for packages?
I'm trying to create a custom ISO for various RH based distros, Oracle Linux and possibly others.
I'd like my ISO to be usable offline, so I want to include all my packages in the ISO.
My kickstart file contains the cdrom option: https://pykickstart.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kickstart-docs.html#cdrom
I've not found much documentation on how this option searches for packages.
I've found that if I only add a kickstart file and change the volume name of my ISO, the cdrom option is no longer able to find package sources.
Could someone explain how this option finds package sources?
